# Set a number of spinners to default

Tags: java, android

I have 18 spinners in a GridLayout with values assigned to each one manually(no adapters) in the activity layout. Now I want a "clear button" to call a method:"onClickClear" that sets each spinner to the default value.

Is there a way to do that without writing a reference to 18 spinners and using setSelection(0). I'm pretty new to Android and this is a proof of concept project I'm doing :)

Comment: No I don't think it's possible. You must have reference to spinners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add all of them to a Spinner array, something like Spinner[] spinners = new Spinner[18]; then spinners[0] = findViewById...
That way you can set them all to the default value easily with a for loop.
for (Spinner spinner : spinners)
spinner.setSelection(0)

Comment: Yes this seems to simplify things a bit. This is what I was looking for. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Laziest and not the best solution.

Find a reference to their parent and loop over it's children

```
for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View currentView = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
    if (currentView instanceof Spinner) {
        ((Spinner) currentView).setSelection(0);
    }
}
```

Or you can hold them in an array and loop over them, but you have to find them 18 times to populate the array.

Comment: It's personal, I don't like solutions with instanceof, I feel like it's a bit hacky, however that solution will work even if you add or remove spinners without change, it's the simplest in terms of effort, and gets the job done

Answer (score 0):

```
Spinner sp = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner); 
sp.setSelection(pos);
```

here pos is integer (your array item position)

array is like below then pos = 0;

```
String str[] = new String{"Select Gender","male", "female" };
```

then in onItemSelected

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> main, View view, int position,
        long Id) {

    if(position > 0){
      // get spinner value
    }else{
      // show toast select gender
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, this I think is the standard way to do it but if you have 18 spinner it's gonna be a long journey. I thought maybe there is more dynamic way of doing this at least for the sake of being short and elegant ;)